# How to deploy Angular 2 application as a standalone (using dist folder)

Tags: angular, deployment, routes

I have finished a development of Angular 2 application and I need to deploy it. I need it to work standalone. So, I tried to move the content of dist folder inside a new apache website, but the routing mechanism doesn't work for some reason, I am getting 404 error when I try to go to /integrations route, for example. During the development, on angular 2 server, /integrations works and Angular 2 routing mechanism works and displays the component without problem. I need the standalone app to also be able to work with different URLs/paths. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Follow following steps* :

**Step 1**: 
 `ng build --prod --env=prod`

**Step 2**. (Copy dist into server)
then dist folder created, copy dist folder and deploy it in root directory of server.

**Step 3**. Creates `.htaccess` file in root folder and paste this in the `.htaccess`

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Actually the --env=prod solved my problem. I found out this myself. I will assing you the correct answer, since it is.

Comment: Yes i know you already created dist folder using production environment. Just wondering you missed .htacces file.  So just explain steps so everyone can follow it.

Comment: I've build the files using `ng build --aot`. Navigations and everything are working fine. When I click on login page it took me there. The issue is that when I refresh the login page it gives **404 not found error**. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to follow [the angular 2 documentation deployment](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/deployment.html#!#fallback)

It explain you how to fallback to index.html and give you an example with apache

Comment: I added that .htaccess, but still no luck. I don't know how to convert this routing thing from angular to javascript.....and this is done automatically, during the transpilation. I am probably doing the .htacces the wrong way or something....

Comment: Did you resolve your issue? Can you post here your .htaccess?